# After updating a field some columns are blank

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a problem after doing an update query. It updates the column I want with the desired description (a string). However the columns which should not be affected by the query are blank instead of having a description ( String). What should I do in order to not acting in these columns?

Here is the query:

```
update GCCC_ATCOM_CLOSING_REASON_I18N a 
set a.DESCRIPTION = (select b.CLOSING_REASON_DESCRIPTION 
                     from GCCC_ATCOM_CLOSING_REASON b 
                     where b.ID_CLOSING_REASON = a.ID_PARENT 
                     AND a.DESCRIPTION ='I HAVE A CAR');
```

In this case it just updates the column that have in the description 'I HAVE A CAR' but the other ones are blank after the update.

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're updating all records and your inner query returns null if description is not `I HAVE A CAR`. Change that to:

```
update GCCC_ATCOM_CLOSING_REASON_I18N a 
set a.DESCRIPTION = 
    (select b.CLOSING_REASON_DESCRIPTION from GCCC_ATCOM_CLOSING_REASON b where b.ID_CLOSING_REASON = a.ID_PARENT)
WHERE a.DESCRIPTION ='I HAVE A CAR'
```

to update only those records that have description `I HAVE A CAR`